# How can I rotate, zoom and drag together in an Image view, with border in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, multi-touch

How can I perform rotate, zoom and drag together in an Android Imageview

Answer (score 2):

For rotate, scale and rotate, [try](http://code.almeros.com/android-multitouch-gesture-detectors#.UVv75zc8Hcd) this. Worked 100%.

Comment: Please add relevant parts of code in your answer. Link only answers are discouraged on SO, because if/when the link changes, the credibility of answer changes too.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
package com.my.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector.OnScaleGestureListener;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ImageViewActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    ImageView view;
    final static String TAG = "TAG";
    ScaleGestureDetector scaleGestureDetector;
    Thread mDrawingThread;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*PinchImageView view = new PinchImageView(this);
        view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

        setContentView(view);*/
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        PinchImageView view = (PinchImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        view.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic));

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button1) {
            PinchImageView view = (PinchImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            view.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic));
        }
        if(v.getId() == R.id.button2) {
            PinchImageView view = (PinchImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
            view.setDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.penguins));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}




/**
 * @author 
 *
 */
public class PinchImageView extends SurfaceView {

    final String TAG = "TAG";
    final static int HORIZONTAL_SNAP_GAP = 30;
    final static int VERTICAL_SNAP_GAP = 50;
    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;

    private Drawable mIcon;
    private float mPosX;
    private float mPosY;

    private float mLastTouchX;
    private float mLastTouchY;
    private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;

    private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleDetector;
    private float mScaleFactor = 1.f;

    public PinchImageView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
    }

    public PinchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public PinchImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        //mIcon = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.pic);
        //mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());

        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.
        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                if(mPosX > HORIZONTAL_SNAP_GAP) mPosX = HORIZONTAL_SNAP_GAP;
                if(mPosY > VERTICAL_SNAP_GAP) mPosY = VERTICAL_SNAP_GAP;
                Display display = ((WindowManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();
                int displayWidth = display.getWidth();
                int displayHeight = display.getHeight();
                if(mPosX + mIcon.getBounds().width() < getWidth() - HORIZONTAL_SNAP_GAP) mPosX = getWidth() - HORIZONTAL_SNAP_GAP - mIcon.getBounds().width();
                if(mPosY + mIcon.getBounds().height() < getHeight() - VERTICAL_SNAP_GAP) mPosY = getHeight() - VERTICAL_SNAP_GAP - mIcon.getBounds().height();

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            /*if(mPosX > 0 || mPosY > 0) {
                Animation an = new TranslateAnimation(mPosX, 0, mPosY, 0);
                an.setDuration(2000);
                an.setRepeatCount(-1);
                //an.initialize(10, 10, 10, 10);

                setAnimation(an);
                an.startNow();
                invalidate();
            }*/
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.save();
        canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
        canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
        if(mIcon != null) mIcon.draw(canvas);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Don't let the object get too small or too large.
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 5.0f));

            invalidate();
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void setDrawable(Drawable draw) {
        mIcon = draw;
        mIcon.setBounds(0, 0, mIcon.getIntrinsicWidth(), mIcon.getIntrinsicHeight());
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Comment: one question of possible (try to adapt it on my own, but maybe u already got the answer) ... i can drag the image as far as i like on the left side, but im not able to do so on the right side...
i can always drag it until the place, where the right edge of the image was, after zooming :)
you got any ideas?